# In Swift, if I have a UITabBarController, how can I popToRootViewController my current navigationController before switching tabs?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITabBarController in a Swift 4 project. The UITabBarController has 3 tabs, each connected to a Navigation Controller via a  relationship segue. Each navigation controller has a series of UIViewControllers connected via show segues. The setup is shown in the picture below.

[Main.storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvqIw.png)

When the user switches tabs, I would like to pop the current navigation controller back to root before loading the new tab view. How can I do this?

Comment: By calling `popToRootViewController(animated:)`?

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear. Once I have a function that has the correct navigationController loaded as a variable, popToRootViewController will achieve the desired result. I'm not sure what function can do this for me.

Comment: Well, how about the tab bar controller’s delegate? It gets an event when we’re about to change tabs...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do so by using this code:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        let tabBarVC = self.window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
        tabBarVC.delegate = self
        return true
    }


    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {

    if  let navVC = tabBarController.selectedViewController as? UINavigationController {
        navVC.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
    }
    return true
}
```

When you will switch tabs, a TabBar delegate will be triggered. There you can check the currently selected view controller, type cast it to navigation controller and then pop to root view controller.

Comment: That almost works. Unfortunately for some reason tabBarController.selectedViewController?.navigationController is showing up as nil. The tabBarController.selectedViewController shows up as an object though.

Comment: I made an edit in the code. Selected View controller is actually a navigation controller. I hope that solve's your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use delgate of taabbar didselect in tabbar controller class  where store the previously stored index and check with the current selected index if it doesnt the same then get the current top viewcontroller and pop that controller to rootviewcontroller.